creating keys for openssh and windows putty keys
I knew there are a lot of answers to this topic. But mine is a special one.
I have an old Linux server with openssl/openssh. On Linux I get for ssh -V: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015.
The windows client shows for ssh -V: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3. Putty is release 0.81.
How do I find a correct key pair in this situation?
Do I have to create a *.ppk file of format 3 or 2. I think format
2. But how to create a working *.pub openssh file out of this?

You need to run an ssh client against your server that tells you which signature algorithms the server supports.
The same should probably exist for putty's command line version (plink, I think???), but if you have any computer with Linux which is able to establish a TCP connection to the target server, a simple
ssh -Q key {your server's ip address or name}

would tell you what it supports.
Just remove the ssh- from the beginnig of these, and you should find the same types as you can generate using your putty tooling or ssh-keygen -t {type}, i.e., "dsa", "ecdsa", "ecdsa-sk", "ed25519", "ed25519-sk", "rsa".
Frankly, 2015 doesn't sound very old, so ed25519 should work. The server is pretty recent (2021) and will in default configurations definitely support ed25519; there should really be no problem here, so, my bet is that this isn't actually a problem with the key pair generation.

But how to create a working *.pub openssh file out of this?
ssh

That OpenSSH-format .pub can be exported directly from Putty tooling; as you initially mentioned, there are really a lot of instructions on the web, but putty's reference manual on Puttygen's "Conversions" menu is all you should need: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.81/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey-puttygen

1.0.1 was EOL several years ago

ssh -Q tells you what your local software has code to implement, not what it is configured to actually use, and not anything at all about what any other system supports or uses. OpenSSH 6.6 does implement ed25519, but that doesn't automatically mean a particular server is configured to allow it, especially if old. ssh -v [user@]host on a nonancient client will show you msg_ext_info specifying sigalgs acceptable to server for userauth IF the server is new enough to send that message -- which 6.6 is not, so you must either look on the server or use trial and error.
